# FBSession.activeSession.isOpen give me False on the 2nd ViewContrller - iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, session-state, facebook-ios-sdk

I have 2 `ViewControllers`.

- 1st ViewController I have a button to login to facebook, working right, giving me the session open state
- 2st ViewController I have some buttons (menu) and here, I want to
  display the photo facebook profile.

I followed [this example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/personalize/#step2) for FacebookSDK 3.2 and iOS 6.1.

**Problem:** 
My `FBSession.activeSession.isOpen` on the 1st `VewController` (Where I did the login) is TRUE and if I go the the 2nd `ViewController` and back the login still on.
On my 2nd `ViewController` (Where I have the `FBProfilePictureView` my `FBSession.activeSession.isOpen` is FALSE.

How I can solve it?

Comment: maybe `singleton` can help you or `delegates`

Comment: How? I'm using the delegate for the [login system](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/)

Comment: Don't use `"activeSession"`, use `Specific` session. I think it can help.

Comment: So, how I use a specific `session`? It is created on the delegate, `@property (strong, nonatomic) FBSession *session;` how I can handle it to be specific?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, what I do:

somewhere you create `@property facebookSession`.
... .h ...

```
@property (nonatomic,strong)FBSession* facebookSession;
```

... .m ...

```
@synthesize facebookSession = _facebookSession;
```

next you should create it:

```
        _facebookSession = [[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID:kAppId
                                                permissions:permissions
                                            urlSchemeSuffix:nil
                                         tokenCacheStrategy:[FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy defaultInstance]

                                ];
```

and after that you should authorize:

```
    [_facebookSession openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
        if(error){
            DLog(@"can't open session with caching strategy!");
        }
        else{
            DLog(@"open session with caching strategy: %@",[[FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy defaultInstance] fetchTokenInformation]);
        }
    }];
```

I recommend you wrap facebook sdk with your own class.

Comment: I don't think you got the point. 1st I don't need the `kAppID` there, I have it on the `plist` file. Then I already have that code on my app (because it's the same off the example). The viewcontroller where I do the login is different of the viewcontroller where I want my `FBSession` open to load the photo profile.

Comment: The only difference is that I call the session on this way: `appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:`